# VFP foreign languages (stored as varbinary) display as readable text

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a cursor with a 'field_blob' datatype W

When I try to retrieve the value of this column, it looks like

```
'0h3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3FEBE5EAE9E8DFEDE720F3FCE3E9E1F2292C203F3F3F3FEAE1F4E1EAFCEAEAE9EDEFF22C2'
```

To save this value to the SQL Server database with datatype `nvarchar(max)` I do:

```
CAST(field_blob as nvarchar(max))
```

- This works fine for languages as English, French, Dutch, ..
- But for foreign languagues like Arabic, it doesn't work, which the binary example should output. It's just an empty string then.

How can I display Arabic text as well? (same problem with Russian, Polish,..)

Comment: Can you select Arabic literals? E.g. `select n'arabic text' from ...`

Comment: No the input i get in foxpro looks like this: '0h3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3FEBE5EAE9E8DFEDE720F3FCE3E9E1F2292C203F3F3F3FEAE1F4E1EAFC'

Comment: Blobs (W) are simply hex representation of any binary value and could only contain characters in range 0..9 and A..F - in other words only hex digits (upper or lowercase). Your sample is not a valid blob.

Comment: Here it is a usefull article about Vfp and Unicode: https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxunicode/foxunicode.asp. I think it will help you.